# sendEmailVerification() with ActionCodeSettings doesn't send email

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

We are using Firebase Email login and try to send an email verification in which after a user clicks on  the verification link, they will be redirected to the Android app. Here is [Firebase's guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/passing-state-in-email-actions)

Here is our sample Kotlin code

```
val settings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
                    .setHandleCodeInApp(false)
                    .setUrl("<our url>")
                    .setDynamicLinkDomain("<our dynamic domain>.page.link")
                    .build()
FirebaseUser.sendEmailVerification(settings)
```

Additional details:

- "our url" is based on an Authorized domains
- "our dynamic domain" is created in Dynamic Links
- We use default email template

We didn't receive any verification email. However, if we called 
`FirebaseUser.sendEmailVerification()`
without ActionCodeSettings, we always received a verification email

What's wrong?

Comment: Also posted on https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1571

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen